# Gas costs do not add up in simple transaction contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, gas, testing

I have a simple contract that helps make a payment to another account. Let's say I start the contract with value `V`, contract gas costs of `G` and value translated into the other account `X`. I assume the following will be true:

`V = G + X`.

However it isn't.

Following a simple `truffle init` step, I am working with the following contract.

`Pay.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

/// @title Pay - Facilitates payments.
contract Pay {
    event Payment(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint amount
    );

    /// @dev Makes a payment.
    /// @param _to Address to pay to.
    function pay(address _to) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        // Does this transfer the right amount of ether (msg.value measured in wei)?
        _to.transfer(msg.value);
        Payment(msg.sender, _to, msg.value);
    }
}
```

And the following test file.

`pay.js`

```
var Pay = artifacts.require("./Pay.sol");

contract('Pay', function(accounts) {
    it("should put money in the first account", function() {
        return Pay.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            pay = instance;
            return web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);
        }).then(function(balance){
            startingBalance = balance.toNumber();
            gasPrice = 200000;
            payAmount = 2500000;
            return pay.pay(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0], value: payAmount, gasPrice: gasPrice });
        }).then(function() {
            return pay.pay.estimateGas(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0], value: payAmount });
        }).then(function(gasCost) {
            gasSpent = gasCost * gasPrice;
            console.log(gasCost);
            console.log(gasPrice);
            console.log(gasSpent);
            return web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);
        }).then(function(balance) {
            endingBalance = balance.toNumber();
            assert.equal(endingBalance - startingBalance, payAmount);
        })
    });
});
```

The output is the following:

```
  Contract: Pay
32001
200000
6400200000
    1) should put money in the first account

    Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

    Payment(_from: 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57, _to: 0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732, amount: 2500000)

    ---------------------------


  0 passing (476ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: Pay should put money in the first account:
     AssertionError: expected 2506752 to equal 2500000
      at test/pay.js:23:20
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
```

In particular, as you see from the output:

`V-X=-6752` (can it even be negative?)
`G=6400200000`

**UPDATE**: Correct answer for reference.

`pay.js`

```
var Pay = artifacts.require("./Pay.sol");

contract('Pay', function(accounts) {
    it("should put money in the first account", function() {
        return Pay.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            pay = instance;
            return web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);
        }).then(function(balance){
            startingBalance = balance;
            gasPrice = 200000;
            payAmount = 2500000;
            return pay.pay(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0], value: payAmount, gasPrice: gasPrice });
        }).then(function(result) {
            gasUsed = result.receipt.gasUsed;
            return pay.pay.estimateGas(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0], value: payAmount });
        }).then(function(gasCost) {
            gasSpent = gasCost * gasPrice;
            return web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]);
        }).then(function(balance) {
            endingBalance = balance;
            assert.equal(endingBalance.sub(startingBalance).toNumber(), payAmount);
        })
    });

    it("should pay gas costs from the second account", function() {
        return Pay.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            pay = instance;
            return web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
        }).then(function(balance){
            startingBalance = balance;
            gasPrice = 200000;
            payAmount = 2500000;
            return pay.pay(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0], value: payAmount, gasPrice: gasPrice });
        }).then(function(result) {
            gasUsed = result.receipt.gasUsed;
            return pay.pay.estimateGas(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0], value: payAmount });
        }).then(function(gasCost) {
            gasSpent = gasCost * gasPrice;
            return web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
        }).then(function(balance) {
            endingBalance = balance;
            assert.equal(startingBalance.sub(endingBalance).toNumber(), payAmount + gasSpent);
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the difference using javascript's numbers

```
startingBalance = balance.toNumber();
...
endingBalance = balance.toNumber();
assert.equal(endingBalance - startingBalance, payAmount);
```

But javascript numbers do not have enough precision to handle large values.

You should store the balance as BigNums and make the conversion to number as the last operation.

```
startingBalance = balance;
...
endingBalance = balance;
assert.equal(endingBalance.sub(startingBalance).toNumber(), payAmount);
```

Also you are paying the operations with `account[0]` you have to use balances from that account to measure gas spent.

---

You are using `estimateGas` to determine use gas used you should use the `gasUsed` field from the [transaction's receipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactionreceipt).

From [eth_estimategas](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_estimategas) documentation

> Note that the estimate may be significantly more than the amount of gas actually used by the transaction, for a variety of reasons including EVM mechanics and node performance.

There are operation that has a negative cost, for example deleting storage will return gas, but it has to succeed first.

Comment: Thanks for this, but when running `result.receipt` I get a gas used of 32001 which corresponds to the estimate above. However, I have to multiply that with gasPrice of 200,000 that I have set. The resulting overall gas fee of 6,400,200,000 does not match the incremental amount paid from the contract.

Comment: @Peteris I've updated my answer, you were using javascript's numbers in your test but it doesn't have enough precision to get the correct result.